# Is there an AspNetCore equivalent of the old WebApi IHttpControllerTypeResolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In WebApi, you could replace the built in `IHttpControllerTypeResolver`, wherein you could discover the Api controllers you wanted in whichever way you felt like.

In AspNetCore with MVC, there's a confusing tangle of PartsManagers and FeatureManagers and somewhere in there is something to do with Controllers. All the documentation and discusion I've been able to find seems to assume that you're a developer working on MVC itself and that you already understand the difference between an ApplicationPartManager and a ControllerFeatureProvider without explaining anything.

What I'd specifically like to do in the simplest example is to start an instance of an AspNetCore 2.0 Kestrel server and have it resolve only a preconfigured hardcoded single controller. I explictly do not want it to do it's normal discovery and all that.

In WebApi, you just did this:

```
public class SingleControllerTypeResolver : IHttpControllerTypeResolver
{
    readonly Type m_type;

    public SingleControllerTypeResolver(Type type) => m_type = type;

    public ICollection<Type> GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver) => new[] { m_type };
}

// ...
// in the configuration:
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new SingleControllerTypeResolver(typeof(MySpecialController)))
```

However I'm stuck trying to get an equivalent using aspnetcore 2

Answer (score 7):

Creating the feature seems simple enough as you can derive from the default `ControllerFeatureProvider` and override the `IsController` to only recognize your desired controller.

```
public class SingleControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider {
    readonly Type m_type;

    public SingleControllerTypeResolver(Type type) => m_type = type;

    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo) {
       return base.IsController(typeInfo) && typeInfo == m_type.GetTypeInfo();
    }
}
```

The next part is to then replace the default provider with your own during start up.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => {
            var originals = apm.FeatureProviders.OfType<ControllerFeatureProvider>().ToList();
            foreach(var original in originals) {
                apm.FeatureProviders.Remove(original);
            }
            apm.FeatureProviders.Add(new SingleControllerFeatureProvider(typeof(MySpecialController)));
        });
        
    //...
}
```

If overriding the default implementation is not considered explicit enough, then you can implement `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` directly and provide `PopulateFeature` yourself.

```
public class SingleControllerFeatureProvider 
    : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature> {
    readonly Type m_type;

    public SingleControllerTypeResolver(Type type) => m_type = type;
    
    public void PopulateFeature(
        IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts,
        ControllerFeature feature) {
        if(!feature.Controllers.Contains(m_type)) {
            feature.Controllers.Add(m_type);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference [Application Parts in ASP.NET Core: Application Feature Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.0#application-feature-providers)
Reference [Discovering Generic Controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680933/discovering-generic-controllers-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: This looks good, however what I want to do is control the *discovery* of the controllers and suppress the built-in discovery. It looks like the SingleControllerFeatureProvider is just going to add my controller and not affect the auto-discovered stuff?

Comment: @OrionEdwards discovery as you describe it was completely changed in core as to what it was before. All the types are extracted form their assemblies via assembly parts. The features will then scan the parts and collect the types relevant to them.

Comment: `apm.FeatureProviders.OfType<ControllerFeatureProvider>().ToList()` - `.ToList()` should be added to avoid enumeration error.

Comment: @aleha good catch. Updated. I appreciate the feedback.