# How to conditionally remove controller from being registered by ASP.NET Core and added to ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have ASP.NET Core solution with standard `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and need to register certain control depending on configuration setting.

Some Example `ApiController` that inherits from `ControllerBase` and all their related actions should only be registered if certain `bool` is true.

Is this possible? I looked at `services.AddMvc()` but I didn't see any option that would easily allow me to either:

- Prevent certain `ExampleController` from being registered
- Remove `ExampleController` and all it's related actions from `IServiceCollection` after being registered

Comment: If im using autofac lib to register my services like this 
            if (!DataSettingsManager.DatabaseIsInstalled)
            {
                if (config.UseFastInstallationService)
                    builder.RegisterType<SqlFileInstallationService>().As<IInstallationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                else
                    builder.RegisterType<CodeFirstInstallationService>().As<IInstallationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }
 so i can able to avoid as per my condition so try with autofac to register controller.

Comment: I think you can find your answer in the link below: [Related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617994/how-to-use-a-controller-in-another-assembly-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0)

Comment: There is also an option to implement custom `IApplicationFeatureProvider` like in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680933/discovering-generic-controllers-in-asp-net-core
You can implement separate `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` that will filter out specific controller types. You can find simple example in this gist: https://gist.github.com/Umqra/89b6f26c539a72bdf8c479d5438000dc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, implement feature filter and register it in your services config:

```cs
public class MyFeatureProvider: ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    private readonly bool condition;

    public MyFeatureProvider(bool condition)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
    }
    
    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo) 
    {
        if (condition && typeInfo.Name == "ExampleController") 
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.IsController(typeInfo);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(mgr => 
        {
            mgr.FeatureProviders.Clear();
            mgr.FeatureProviders.Add(new MyFeatureProvider(true));
        });            
    }
}
```

I'll link [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5ff9ed68d1cf6c89d72d27a69b00ed0ecd34daed/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs) in case you'd like to check out stock standard implementation and see how it works for reference

Comment: Does not work for me... Endpoints are still  accessible...
(Debugged the IsController method which returns false on the ExampleController)

Comment: I think the part of removing the existing ControllerFeatureProvider is missing see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382268/199252

Comment: @Roel You might probably want to remove only existing `ControllerFeatureProvider`s, not all `FeatureProvider`s.

Comment: On default you only have the existing one and this is the place to add your own custom ones.