# How to hide OData Metadata Controller in Swagger?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata, .net-6.0

After updating my project to .NET6 and OData to 8.0.4, a new Metadata controller with these endpoints appeared:

[image]

I want to disable it somehow or remove it from my service.

Code for adding OData service:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllers(mvcOptions => mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("", GetEdmModel()).Select().Expand());
}
```

Versions:

- .NET6
- ASP.NET Core 6
- OData 8.0.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several options to solve this:

1. You can use [the Controller feature provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680933/discovering-generic-controllers-in-asp-net-core) to exclude `MetadataController`
2. You can use `Conventions` in `ODataOptions` to remove `MetadataRoutingConvention`.
3. You can implement `DocumentFilter` to hide `MetadataController` and related schemas from the Swagger

#2 is the simplest way:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt =>
   {
         opt.Conventions.Remove(opt.Conventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>().First());
         opt.AddRouteComponents("", GetEdmModel()).Select().Expand();
    });
```

#3 If you just want to hide `MetadataController` and related schemas from the Swagger:

```
public class SwaggerODataControllerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // remove controller
        foreach (ApiDescription apiDescription in context.ApiDescriptions)
        {
            var actionDescriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)apiDescription.ActionDescriptor;
            if (actionDescriptor.ControllerName == "Metadata")
            {
                swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove($"/{apiDescription.RelativePath}");
            }
        }

        // remove schemas
        foreach ((string key, _) in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
        {
            if (key.Contains("Edm") || key.Contains("OData"))
            {
                swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to the `services.AddSwaggerGen`:

```
cfg.DocumentFilter<SwaggerODataControllerDocumentFilter>();
```

For option #1 you can do like:

```
public class RemoveMetadataControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
    {
        protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
        {
            if (typeInfo.FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers.MetadataController")
            {
                // or just compare the name
                return false;
            }

            return base.IsController(typeInfo);
        }
    }
```

In the startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
     {
       manager.FeatureProviders.Remove(manager.FeatureProviders.OfType<ControllerFeatureProvider>().FirstOrDefault());
          manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new RemoveMetadataControllerFeatureProvider());
     }).AddOData(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the similar problem. I get the solution by

- removing odata service injection from startup file (because swagger automatically add metadata classes if I tried to inject odata from startup)
- downgrading OData from 8.0.4 to 8.0.0
- and implementing ODataQueryOptions inside controller instead of EnableQuery actionfilter
- used ODataBuilder/OdataModelBuilder within controller instead of startup. in my case it is ODataBuilder

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will check that. I'll give you an answer.

Comment: Are you  injecting OData in Controller? Also I have already implemented  attribute. Added in question.